# What do I have to do to remove all traces of a github account from my local computer?

Tags: github

I deleted the account on Github and will be creating a new account (for reasons that are unimportant). What do I have to remove from my local machine to avoid conflicts with the old accounts that I used to push to etc. For example, I'm sure I created things like authentication keys on my local machine that are linked to that deleted account and will make it difficult to push to a new account.

Answer (score 0):

For each of your repositories that were linked to github, you will want to change the remote references by [deleting the old remote](https://help.github.com/articles/removing-a-remote)  add adding the new one:

```
git remote add origin git@github.com:your_new_account/repo_name.git
```

Keeping the old ssh keys around shouldn't be a problem.